# Why are the spark plugs from the same 2 cylinders corroding faster than the others?

Tags: dodge, sparkplugs, truck, diagnostics

On my engine ('99, 360 v8 Magnum), I replaced the spark plugs less than 15k miles ago, because of misfires in cylinders 2 and 8. Those two plugs were badly corroded. Today I had to replace them again, and the same 2 were far more corroded than the others.

Because I have found evidence of a head gasket leak (burned coolant smell in exhaust and loss of coolant), I was thinking perhaps the coolant was getting into those 2 cylinders and causing faster corrosion. Is that likely? If not, what's causing the rapid deterioration?

Cylinder 8's plug:
[image]

Cylinder 2's plug:
[image]

All the plugs:
[image]

Comment: What you see could very well be burned coolant as well as oil.  As the glycerin burns in the combustion process it can be corrosive to spark plug electrode.

Comment: That fourth one from the left is especially worrying as well. That electrode is tweaked really bad. Preignition can also wear electrodes down like you're seeing on #2 and 8. Not sure if it's caused by that or the coolant though.

Comment: I would be surprised if it was pre ignition, in a short stroke engine.  If I replace the head gaskets I suppose that will show for certain whether or not it is coolant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you see could very well be burned coolant as well as oil.  As the glycerin burns in the combustion process it can take on corrosive properties that degrade the electrodes.

Typically with oil in the combustion chamber you don't see as sever of a an electrode degradation as illustrated in your photos.

I think your head gasket change is looming and should probably get done sooner rather than later.

IMO this is a combination of both coolant and oil in your combustion chamber.

Answer (score 2):

i am sure the engine gasket, pistons rings or cylinders are the problem. if you have high mileage are the rings or cylinders,if you run the car without coolant or is running hot is the gasket.
the worst case scenario is a crack in the engine block

Comment: Can you explain further the last point please